# Angular, can not create new project

Tags: node.js, angular

so i have problem with creating new project in angular. I reinstalled server, updated my server, installed apache2, nodejs, npm, and angular/cli. My server is Ubuntu 16.04.

```
nodejs -v: v8.12.0
npm -v: 6.4.1
ng -v: Angular CLI: 6.2.3
Node: 8.12.0
OS: linux x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.3
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.3
@schematics/angular          0.8.3
@schematics/update           0.8.3
rxjs                         6.2.2
typescript                   2.9.2
```

next i went to my `/var/www/html` folder and typed `sudo ng new my-app`
 and here is the problem:

```
CREATE my-app/README.md (1022 bytes)
CREATE my-app/angular.json (3548 bytes)
CREATE my-app/package.json (1312 bytes)
CREATE my-app/tsconfig.json (408 bytes)
CREATE my-app/tslint.json (2837 bytes)
CREATE my-app/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
CREATE my-app/.gitignore (503 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/index.html (292 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/main.ts (373 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/polyfills.ts (3194 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/browserslist (388 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/karma.conf.js (964 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/tsconfig.app.json (166 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/tsconfig.spec.json (256 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/app/app.component.html (1141 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (995 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/app/app.component.ts (210 bytes)
CREATE my-app/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE my-app/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
CREATE my-app/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (302 bytes)
CREATE my-app/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)

> node-sass@4.9.3 install /var/www/html/my-app/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js


Package install failed, see above.
```

I am new to nodejs, angular and want to learn it but i can not because i can not create new project.

Comment: Can you show us the error you are getting?

Comment: try without dash in project name

Comment: I seem to remember that at least some npm versions refuse to run as root. Try as a normal user in a directory where this user has write access.

Comment: try running `ng new project-name`, dont use sudo.

Comment: dash in project name doesn't create any problem @tano

Comment: it seems to be problem with `node-sass@4.9.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i find solution.

I have my ubuntu as vps so i forgot to set up host ip and port:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000
```

Change (0.0.0.0 to ip you want). This worked for me.